# Automator adding unwanted line breaks

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm using Automator to create an HTML page and everything works great but I'm running into one small problem. The user is asked for information at the beginning that is then set into variables. The page is created by grabbing some code using Get Specified Text and copying it to the clipboard, getting one of the variables and then putting them both into a text document. This process is then repeated several times, eventually creating an HTML file. I'm running into issues because Automator is creating line breaks (maybe carriage returns?) in between each bit of specified text and each variable. So, what I want to look like this:

```
<code grabbed using "Get Specified Text" followed by a Variable. And now some more text and another Variable.>
```

ends up looking like this:

```
<code grabbed using "Get Specified Text" followed by a
Variable
. And now some more text and another 
Variable
.>
```

This is breaking my page in a few parts. Is there a way to prevent these line breaks?

Comment: What are you doing to assemble the variable and clipboard text?

Comment: I'm opening a new TextEdit document, using Get Specified Text to get a specific bit of code, using Copy to Clipboard to put that code into the clipboard, using Get Value of Variable to call one of the variables that was defined at the beginning and the Set Contents of TextEdit to place both of them in the document. The just repeating that for other instances of code and other variables, appending them to the end of the document.

Comment: That isn’t going to work - the items returned by the various actions are passed along as a _list_, which get separated by newlines when pasted into the document.  Try adding a **Run Shell Script** action (with `Pass Input: to stdin` and the script set to `cat`) immediately before the action outputting to the file (this will concatenate the items).

Comment: Awesome, I'll give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't seem to be working. I'm using Get Specified Text and then copying to the clipboard. I'm then running the shell script with cat and the Pass Input to stdin and then I'm calling the variable and then Setting Contents, but nothing has changed. I also tried running the shell script immediately before the Set Contents but that didn't make a difference. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Try changing the **Run Shell Script** to `Pass input: as arguments` with `echo "$*"` - make sure there isn't an extra return in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items passed along from action to action are in a *list*, so it appears that setting the TextEdit contents separates the individual items by a newline, which is the normal paragraph delimiter.

Many of the text actions assume TextEdit and/or rich text and don’t use variables (or get along with other plain text actions), so a **Run AppleScript** action can be used before an action to convert or concatenate items, for example (Mojave):

[image]

Automator (or TextEdit for that matter) isn’t really a very good tool for HTML editing.  You might take a look at [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) (the light version is free), which also has excellent AppleScript support.

EDIT:

Use the following in a **Run AppleScript** action to combine the text using a specified delimiter (this example uses an empty string):

```
on run {input, parameters}
  set separator to "" -- text to separate the items with
  set tempTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
  set AppleScript's text item delimiters to separator
  set output to input as text
  set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tempTID
  return output
end run
```

Comment: This is almost there. It's just inserting a space between the concatenated paragraphs.

Comment: And I obviously don't want it to remove ALL the spaces, just the spaces between the concatenated strings.

Comment: You just aren’t going to get that kind of control using regular Automator actions - they aren't really designed for that.  Other options would be to provide most of the functionality within a **Run AppleScript** or **Run Shell Script** action (using  Automator to get information for the script), or use a script by itself.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to use a **Run AppleScript** action to combine the text items.

Comment: That's just about it. It's concatenating the string and the variable perfectly. The only hiccup is that when I then move into the next string and variable using this same method, it's on the next line instead of concatenating it with the previous ones. Maybe I can try messing around with cutting the newly made line into the clipboard and concatenating it with the next ones or something. Seems like a bit of a hack but it could work. You're amazing!

Comment: I think that is an artifact of using the TextEdit action (if you remember, it sticks newlines in there).  AppleScript can also write to text files, so it is sounding more and more like a regular script would be the way to go if your workflow is going to be getting much more complex.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I create everything as I was before with each item on it's separate line, then grab it all using Get Contents and then run your commands and paste it back to the document using Replace instead of append and it's properly concatenated.